# Linq how to sort and select Distinc in the same line

Tags: linq, sorting, distinct

I appreciate your indication about how to sort on the same line the next instruction.

Thank you very much!

```
 this.ProductosUnicos = this.repository.TemperatureReports.AsEnumerable().Select(tt => tt.Producto).Distinct().ToList();


public List<String> ProductosUnicos
{
    get
    {
        return this._productosunicos;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (this._productosunicos == value)
            return;

        this._productosunicos = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ProductosUnicos");
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 Sort by _what_? What have you tried to sort, what types are involved, what is `TemperatureReports`, what `Producto`, what do you want as result?

Comment: Hi Tim, for the unique field selected. Producto. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting there are `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` extension methods:

```
reports
    .Select(tt => tt.Producto)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(p => p)
    .ToList();
```

The `OrderBy` expects an expression that will be evaluated for each item in the sequence. The resulting sequence will be sorted based on the returned value from the expression.

Comment: Hi. Does not work p.name or p.Producto, not let me select.. What could be happend? Thanks. Charles.

Comment: p.Name is just an example of a selector expression. I don't know the type of tt.Producto. If it is just a string or another primitive type, than you can just use OrderBy(p => p). If it has a property that you need to sort on, than you need to select that property in the expression.

Comment: I have updated the answer, so it demonstrates how to sort a sequence of string values (which seems to be the type of a Producto).

Comment: Of course, I'm a bit new here, could you tell me where can i  mark please?

Comment: There should be a button below the upvote and downvote for the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask